# How to trim user input in bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

OK, here is a given user input
:

```
$ myscript.sh file-name.txt
```

I would like to trim "file-name.txt" to retrive 'file' in bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1

# trim text after '-' from user input 'file-name.txt'
# save 'file' back to $1
```

My best guess is mixing sed and regular expression somehow, 
but I am no expert of those :(

Any ideas?

---

I tried muru's suggestion for more complicated input.

given input : A-B-C-D-0.1.5-6.1.txt

wanted output : A-B-C-D

```
#!/bin/bash
TRIMMED1="${1%-*}"
TRIMMED2="${1%%-*}"
TRIMMED3="${TRIMMED1%-*}"
TRIMMED4="${TRIMMED1%%-*}"
TRIMMED5="${1%-[0-9]*}"
TRIMMED6="${1%%-[0-9]*}"
echo "user input : $1"
echo "TRIMMED1 : $TRIMMED1"
echo "TRIMMED2 : $TRIMMED2"
echo "TRIMMED3 : $TRIMMED3"
echo "TRIMMED4 : $TRIMMED4"
echo "TRIMMED5 : $TRIMMED5"
echo "TRIMMED6 : $TRIMMED6"
```

result:

```
user input : A-B-C-D-0.1.5-6.1.txt
TRIMMED1 : A-B-C-D-0.1.5
TRIMMED2 : A
TRIMMED3 : A-B-C-D
TRIMMED4 : A
TRIMMED5 : A-B-C-D-0.1.5
TRIMMED6 : A-B-C-D
```

Comment: Before or after '-'?

Comment: i need a portion before '-'

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: `TRIMMED3` is supposed to re-use `TRIMMED2`, so the line should actually be `TRIMMED3="${TRIMMED2%%-*}"` , and yes - my mistake there - `TRIMMED2` and `TRIMMED3` should use `%`, not `%%`.

Comment: i tried `TRIMMED3="${TRIMMED2%%-*}"` and it returned `A`

Comment: yes, using `%` gives the wanted output

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe  found a good info regarding substring removal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to use external tools for this. Pure bash:

```
FILENAME="${1%-*}"
```

`%` is used to remove the shortest matching suffix. If you have `file-name-foo`, you'll get `file-name`. To remove the longest matching suffix, use `%%`.

To save to `$1`, you'll have to use `set`. Something like:

```
set -- "${1%-*}" "${@:2}"
```

Then the next time you use `$1`, it will have the trimmed text.

Remember, no spaces around `=` when assigning variables.

Comment: what does ${@:2} means?

Comment: @RNA all the arguments, from the second onwards (essentially, `"$2" "$3" "$4" …`), empty if you have only one argument. What that line does is set the arguments, but using a different string for the first argument.

Comment: Could you please add a link to "${1%-*}" "${@:2}" etc guide? have no idea what to google :)

Comment: @Putnik the BashFAQ is a good resource: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Retrieving_values_from_an_array and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Comment: I got a more complicated case, (input: A-B-C-D-1.1-2.txt), (supposed output:A-B-C-D)
How can I trim in this case?

Comment: @RNA how did you determine the supposed output?

Comment: `A-B-C-D` is the name of package, `1.1` is version, `2` is some sort of subversion number.  I need to retrieve name of package to uninstall it with `rpm` command.  `rpm -e A-B-C-D`

Comment: @RNA if the version number's guaranteed to start with a digit, maybe: `${1%-[0-9]*}`, (though that may trip over entries like `foo-9bar-1.2-3`. Or apply `%%` twice: `a=${1%%-*}; a=${a%%-*}` to remove the last two hyphen-separated fields

Comment: Now I clearly understood how to use it. Appreciate you!!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1
TRIMMED=$(echo "$FILENAME" | cut -f1 -d-)
```

The command will output field 1 using `-` as a delimeter.

Comment: I fixed it. I put `f` and `d` at wrong places. Now it is OK.

Comment: No, I do not...

Comment: i tried ur method and it gives un-trimmed $1

Comment: @muru The other quotes are no needed either I guess ;-)

Comment: You can't assign to `$1` that way, unfortunately. Those quotes are needed: what will happen if filename is, for example: `fi   le-name.txt`?

Comment: OK. I see it. So assign to something else.

Comment: @RNA I fixed it. You can assign to some other var

Comment: yes, it worked!!

Comment: you edited your answer like 3 times per min, couldn't catch up that fast :P

Answer (score 4):

Can be done like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# trim text after '-' from user input 'file-name.txt'
FILENAME="$(sed 's/-.*//' <<< $1).txt"

# save 'file' back to $1
mv "$1" "$FILENAME"
```

Explanation:

In my example I use the `sed` command to shorten the name which usually has this layout `'command/search/replacement/'`. In my example above i use `s` as command which is search and replace, then `-.*` as search word (regex) which will search all combinations beginning with a `-` then followed by a random character `.` and telling it this keeps on till the end with `*`. The replacement string I leave empty, this means `file-name.txt` becomes `file`.

The `<<<` is `bash` specific and is called a here-string, so this wont work in `sh`. It is like the redirections into files just that it redirects a string into the stream instead of a file.

Finaly to make the string complete I add `.txt` back and then do a `mv` to rename the file.

Comment: I did not catch that OP wanted to `mv` the file.

Comment: Np, you still can add it in your answer, all here are valid so far.

Comment: little more explanation on the role of <<<, please.

Comment: Added it into my answer.